# Python SQLAlchemy TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when trying to instantiate model with one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to create a model which contains a one-to-many relationship. One recipe may have many directions associated with it. However, when I try to instantiate a recipe I get **TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'**. If I remove the directions argument everything works fine and it creates the recipe without any directions. Is there something I'm missing that won't allow the directions parameter to be a list?

app.py

```
data = {
  'cook_time': 15,
  'description': 'Recipe description',
  'directions': [{'order': 1, 'text': 'First direction'},
                 {'order': 2, 'text': 'Second direction'}],
  'image_url': 'https://via.placeholder.com/800x300?text=Recipe+Image',
  'name': 'Test recipe 2',
  'prep_time': 15,
  'servings': 6
}

recipe = models.Recipe(
  name=data['name'],
  description=data['description'],
  image_url=data['image_url'],
  prep_time=data['prep_time'],
  cook_time=data['cook_time'],
  servings=data['servings'],
  directions=data['directions']
)
```

models.py

```
class Recipe(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'recipes'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True)
   description = db.Column(db.String(2000))
   image_url = db.Column(db.String(200))
   prep_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
   cook_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
   servings = db.Column(db.Integer)

   directions = db.relationship('RecipeDirection', backref='recipes', lazy='dynamic')


class RecipeDirection(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'recipe_directions'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
   order = db.Column(db.Integer)
   text = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because SQLAlchemy is expecting directions to be a list of `RecipeDirection`.  To fix, create a list of `RecipeDirection` first.

```py
data = {
  'cook_time': 15,
  'description': 'Recipe description',
  'directions': [{'order': 1, 'text': 'First direction'},
                 {'order': 2, 'text': 'Second direction'}],
  'image_url': 'https://via.placeholder.com/800x300?text=Recipe+Image',
  'name': 'Test recipe 2',
  'prep_time': 15,
  'servings': 6
}

# Create a list of `RecipeDirection`
directions = []
for direction in data.get("directions", []):
    directions.append(models.RecipeDirection(**direction))

recipe = models.Recipe(
  name=data['name'],
  description=data['description'],
  image_url=data['image_url'],
  prep_time=data['prep_time'],
  cook_time=data['cook_time'],
  servings=data['servings'],
  directions=directions  # Now list of RecipieDirection not list of dicts
)
```

I would also suggest looking into a serilizer that will take care of some of the details of marshalling and serilizing nested data structures for you, such as [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)